# Python - 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax' - can't find the reason

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to fix it but can't find why the error keeps appearing

```
job_lists = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobs-search__results-list")
```

My best guess was that there was an indentation issue with the above while statement, but I tried to fix it and the problem is still there. I'm an absolute beginner though, so there must be something I'm missing. Here's the chunk of code I'm referring to:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
import pandas as pd
url = 'URL'
s = Service('PATH\\chromedriver.exe')
wd = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)
wd.get(url)
no_of_jobs = int(float(wd.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1>span").get_attribute('innerText')))
i = 2
while i <= int(no_of_jobs/25)+1:
    wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    i = i + 1
    try:
        wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div/section/button").click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except ValueError:
        pass
        time.sleep(5)
job_lists = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobs-search__results-list")
jobs = job_lists.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"li") # return a list
```

This is the error message I get:

```
... job_lists = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobs-search__results-list")
  File "<stdin>", line 10
    job_lists = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobs-search__results-list")
    ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: You can't have `pass` and then more code below that within the same level of indentation. What are you trying to do there? Can you comment out or delete the `pass`, and see if that works?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! So what I'm trying to do is to scrape LinkedIn Job postings. I started from this article I found (https://maoviola.medium.com/a-complete-guide-to-web-scraping-linkedin-job-postings-ad290fcaa97f) and made some adjustments because it didn't seem to work. 

That bit of code is supposed to browse the jobs. Linkedin works in a way that it loads more jobs if you scroll down the browser bar. After a bit though, you have to click "see more jobs" to load other offerings. 
To accommodate both of the scenarios, the author added the ‘try — except’ procedure.

Comment: I tried to delete the `pass` but it is still not working

Comment: Still seeing _Syntax Error: invalid syntax_ implementing the suggestion from @mechanical_meat ?

Comment: OP: Put the actual error message/traceback in the question. That might have more information. As it is, I can't see anything else going wrong.

Comment: Yeah! Same error as before...I think there's something wrong with the indentation

Comment: This is the error I get




`... job_lists = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobs-search__results-list")
  File "<stdin>", line 10
    job_lists = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobs-search__results-list")
    ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>`

Comment: You are apparently pasting your code into a Python interpreter, rather that saving it in a .py file and running that file.  In the interactive interpreter, multi-line statements (such as the `while` loop just above the line producing the error) have to be terminated by a blank line, before you can enter another line at the same level.

Comment: Yes I am indeed...I tried to add a blank line with "\" 
after the `except` statement, but it doesn't seem to be working...am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The normal Python REPL/interpreter doesn't typically handle multiline input as well as say ipython. I suggest either using ipython, or a Jupyter Notebook, or just running the code via a file as another commenter suggested.